# No provider for ConnectionBackend for ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

im using ionic 2 and i create a simple service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class EliteApi {

  private baseUrl="https://myurl.com";
    constructor(private http:Http) { }

    getTournaments(){
      return new Promise(resolve =>{
        this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'tournaments.json').subscribe(res => resolve(res.json()));

      });
    }
}
```

then i import it on app.component.ts like this to register the service

```
import { EliteApi } from './shared/shared';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [EliteApi,Http]
})
```

after that on my page i import the service

```
import { EliteApi } from '../../app/shared/shared';
```

and on the event loaded i wrote this to get the json data

```
  ionViewLoaded(){
    this.eliteApi.getTournaments().then(data => this.tournaments = data);
  }
```

it gives me exception says
No provider for ConnectionBackend!

i tried as some question similar here says put the service on providers as this

@NgModule({
  providers: [ EliteApi

but also the same error

Answer (score 7):

Have you import the `HttpModule` in your `App` module?

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
   imports: [HttpModule]
})
```

Comment: i add import { HttpModule} from "@angular/http"; on top of app .component.ts and add it to import of the sme file like this

Comment: imports: [ HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ], still the same error

Answer (score 2):

the problem solved  when I type my code in the event `ionViewWillLoad` or `ionViewDidLoad`  not `ionViewLoaded`

also the code works fine when I import HttpModule on app.component.ts

```
import { HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
```

and add it to providers like this

```
  providers: [EliteApi,HttpModule]
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to inject the service in constructor before using it like below:

```
constructor(public eliteApi:EliteApi){ }
```

Comment: the service is alreay inserted in the constructor like this    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private eliteApi: EliteApi) {
  }

Comment: oh i solved the problem it was the event i wrote my code in it should be ionViewWillLoad or iobViewDidLoad  not the one i put above ionViewLoaded