# No provider for ConnectionBackend、RequestOptions

Tags: angular, ionic2

Recently i created a application by Ionic2.
I started the job with the command

```
$ ionic start MyIonicProject tabs
```

And then I wanted to make a get or post request in the Home.ts's file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { md5 } from 'blueimp-md5';
import { Http,ConnectionBackend,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers:[Http]
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private http:Http) {

  }
}
```

and the error is 
No provider for ConnectionBackend! Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend!....
It should have been easy，but I don't know how to solve it. And I search the error from google，i tryed，but the result don't fit my problem

Comment: The first result in google gives the exact same question (plus answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389126/no-provider-for-connectionbackend-for-ionic-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for ConnectionBackend for ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389126/no-provider-for-connectionbackend-for-ionic-2)